# Resize and compress images before uploading to Google Cloud storage

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimage, resize, compression

I've made a function to resize the image to a maximum width and height while keeping the aspect ratio. In addition I'm compressing the image based on compressionQuality - I've tested this with a 3024x4032 jpeg image @ 11.7 mb.

```
maxWidth = 800px
maxHeight = 1200px
compressionQuality = 0.5
```

The function do reduce the image size from 11.7mb to 0.51 mb, however the width and height is not reduced correctly. After uploading to Firebase the image is 1600 x 2134px twice the size ... but it should be 800x1066px (half)

Can you see what is wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ImageEdit {
        static let instance = ImageEdit()

    func resizeAndCompressImageWith(image: UIImage, maxWidth: CGFloat, maxHeight: CGFloat, compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data? {

    let horizontalRatio = maxWidth / image.size.width
    let verticalRatio = maxHeight / image.size.height


    let ratio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)

    let newSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width * ratio, height: image.size.height * ratio)
    var newImage: UIImage

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
        renderFormat.opaque = false
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height), format: renderFormat)
        newImage = renderer.image {
            (context) in
            image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        }
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height), true, 0)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, compressionQuality)



    return data

}

}
```

This is the code that upload the image to firebase.

```
func uploadImageToFirebaseAndReturnImageURL(directory: String, image: UIImage!, maxWidth: CGFloat, maxHeight: CGFloat, compressionQuality: CGFloat, handler: @escaping(_ imageURL: String)  -> ()) {
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString // create unique image name

        if let uploadData = ImageEdit.instance.resizeAndCompressImageWith(image: image, maxWidth: maxWidth, maxHeight: maxHeight, compressionQuality: compressionQuality) {

            DB_STORE.child(directory).child(imageName).putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error ?? "Image upload failed for unknown reason")
                    return
                }

                // if URL exist, then return imageURL
                if let imageURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                  handler (imageURL)


                }
                return

            })
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code into a test project and added some print statements and tried resizing an image with an original size of 3360x2108. (Note: I'm using force unwraps in this test code but wouldn't recommend it for any production code).

Here's my function that calls your resizing code:

```
func resizeImage() {
    guard let image = UIImage.init(named: "landscape") else {
        return
    }
    print("Original Image Size: width: \(image.size.width) height: \(image.size.height)")

    let _ = ImageEdit.instance.resizeAndCompressImageWith(image: image, maxWidth: 800.0, maxHeight: 1200.0, compressionQuality: 0.5)
}
```

Here's my updated version of your resizing code. I simply adding some code to instantiate some image instances at the end to log out their actual size after conversion:

```
import UIKit

class ImageEdit {
    static let instance = ImageEdit()

    func resizeAndCompressImageWith(image: UIImage, maxWidth: CGFloat, maxHeight: CGFloat, compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data? {

        let horizontalRatio = maxWidth / image.size.width
        let verticalRatio = maxHeight / image.size.height


        let ratio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
        print("Image Ratio: \(ratio)")

        let newSize = CGSize(width: image.size.width * ratio, height: image.size.height * ratio)
        print("NewSize: \(String(describing: newSize))")
        var newImage: UIImage

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            print("UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat")
            let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
            renderFormat.opaque = false
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height), format: renderFormat)
            newImage = renderer.image {
                (context) in
                image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
            }
        } else {
            print("UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions")
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height), true, 0)
            image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
            newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        print("NewImageSize: width: \(newImage.size.width) height: \(newImage.size.height)")

        let png = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)
        let pngImg = UIImage.init(data: png!)!
        print("PNG - width: \(pngImg.size.width) - height: \(pngImg.size.height)")

        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, compressionQuality)
        let jpgImg = UIImage.init(data: data!)!
        print("JPG - width: \(jpgImg.size.width) - height: \(jpgImg.size.height)")

        let fullData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0)
        let jpgFull = UIImage.init(data: fullData!)!
        print("JPG FULL - width: \(jpgFull.size.width) - height: \(jpgFull.size.height)")

        return data

    }
}
```

When running this on the simulator with iOS 11 I get this logged to the debugger:

```
Original Image Size: width: 3360.0 height: 2108.0
Image Ratio: 0.238095238095238
NewSize: (800.0, 501.904761904762)
UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat
NewImageSize: width: 800.0 height: 502.0
PNG - width: 2400.0 - height: 1506.0
JPG - width: 2400.0 - height: 1506.0
JPG FULL - width: 2400.0 - height: 1506.0
```

If I comment out your

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
```

block I still see the same measurement results.

So it seems that the newImage generated directly from

```
UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat 
or 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions
```

generates an image with the size you specified. However, for some reason running that image through

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)
or
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, compressionQuality)
```

results in an image whose dimensions are 3x larger than the original image. Even when I update

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
to
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
```

it doesn't seem to matter.

In my test case UIScreen.main.scale = 3.0.

So it appears that converting the image via PNG or JPEG representation methods multiplies it by whatever the UIScreen.main.scale is for the final image size generated by those functions.

Comment: Thanks for this effort. Its odd that the UIScreen.main.scale should have an implication on the scaling... is it an error in Xcode?

Comment: I'm not sure, it doesn't make sense to me, I'll experiment with it some more today. One thing I noticed, if you run UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRepresentation on the original image without running it through the resize operation first the resulting image size is the same as the original size, not 3x bigger, which seems really weird to me.

Comment: Same here, still trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the exact same feature for my project. However, I believe your current result is the expected outcome. Since you don't set the UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.scale or the scale parameter in the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, it uses the device's main screen scale. By setting the scale to 1.0, you can use your desired CGSize as input to these methods and get the desired UIImage and UIImagePNG/JPEGRepresentation size.